# Can we use HDFS to store git repositories?

Tags: git, hadoop, repository, hdfs, gitlab

I want to create a scalable git repository both for high availability, automatic failover and performance. I think that HDFS is well suited for such cases. But I don't know if it is possible to use it with git repositories.

Can somebody show an example? How to use hdfs to store git repository?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably a bit lengthy but should work is to use FUSE (MountableHDFS) once you are able to mount HDFS it is just like any other file system and you should be able to use that mount (HDFS) to store git repository. see below links for details

https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/MountableHDFS

http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/cdh/5-1-x/CDH5-Installation-Guide/cdh5ig_hdfs_mountable.html

Comment: Please note: I have used a similar HDFS NFS setup to store and interact with git repos and have and some problems in the past (using MapR Hadoop). Eg. not being able to branch due to permission errors between NFS mount dirs and the 'actual' HDFS dirs, git being unable to set symlinks, etc. Basically, please have enough git knowledge (which I didn't have) to untangle some git problems if things don't workout smoothly.

Comment: is there anything wrong with using the NFS Gateway as described in the hadoop docs? https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.0.3/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsNfsGateway.html